# Yii2 - search by latest of hasMany relation

Tags: yii2, relation

I have ActiveRecord models named Task and Test. Task may contain several tests (or zero).

Relations in `Task` model:

```
public function getTests(){
    return $this->hasMany(Test::className(), ['task_num' => 'task_num']);
}

public function getLastTest(){
    return $this->hasOne(Test::className(), ['task_num' => 'task_num'])->addOrderBy(['test_num' => SORT_DESC])->limit(1);
}
```

As expected, `lastTest` relation doesn't work as I want. I need this relation to make search. I need to filter all tasks with status equal to 3 which have tests and the latest one has status not equal to 4.

`TaskSearch` model:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Task::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    // standart search content
    // ...
    // ...


    // TASK_COMPLETE is 3
    // TEST_COMPLETE is 4
    $query->andFilterWhere(['tbl_task.status' => TASK_COMPLETE]);
    $query->joinWith(['lastTest' => function($q){
        $q->where('tbl_test.status <> ' . TEST_COMPLETE);
    }]);    

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Resulting sql query is:

```
SELECT `tbl_task`.*
FROM `tbl_task`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_test` ON `tbl_task`.`task_num` = `tbl_test`.`task_num`
WHERE (`tbl_task`.`status`=3) AND (tbl_test.status <> 4)
ORDER BY `task_num` DESC, `test_num` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query finds all tasks with *at least one test* which status is not equal to 4, but I need to find only tasks with *only last test status is not equal to 4* or without tests at all.

How do I define necessary relation and set up search method?

Edit:

via trial and errors I found correct sql query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_task t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_test t2 ON t1.task_num = t2.task_num
WHERE
   (t1.status = 3) AND 
   (t2.status <> 4) AND
   (t2.test_num = (SELECT MAX(t3.test_num) FROM tbl_test t3 LEFT JOIN tbl_task t4 ON t3.task_num = t4.task_num))
```

How can I make this query from the `search` method?

Edit 2:

I was wrong, this query doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it via subquery.

My solution is:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['tbl_task.status' => TASK_COMPLETE]);
$query->joinWith(['lastTest' => function($q){
   $q->where('tbl_test.status <> ' . TEST_COMPLETE);
}]);
$query->andWhere('(tbl_test.test_num = (SELECT MAX(t1.test_num) FROM tbl_test t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_task t2 ON t1.task_num = t2.task_num WHERE t2.task_num = tbl_task.task_num GROUP BY t2.task_num))');
```

Isn't very clean solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getLastTest(){
    return $this->getTests()->addOrderBy(['test_num' => SORT_DESC])->limit(1);
}
```

And then this:

```
$query = Task::find();
$query->joinWith('lastTest as lt');
$query->andFilterWhere(['tbl_task.status' => TASK_COMPLETE]);
$query->andFilterWhere('lt.status <> ' . TEST_COMPLETE);
```

Comment: Nothing changed, query is still exactly the same.

Comment: last line gives error since parameter must be array. Changing to $query->andFilterWhere(['<>', 'lt.status', TEST_COMPLETE]) clears error, but resulting query is: `SELECT `tbl_task`.* FROM `tbl_task` LEFT JOIN `tbl_test` `lt` ON `tbl_task`.`task_num` = `lt`.`task_num` WHERE (`tbl_task`.`status`=3) AND (`lt`.`status` <> 4) ORDER BY `task_num` DESC, `test_num` DESC LIMIT 10`